# load single fragment twice in one activity with 2 questions from local json file

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a local json for survey questions and i have created one fragment and activity on which i want to show fragment with next and previous button on activity. my problem is that i want to show same fragment twice with two different questions at same time and also preserve the state for next and previous. for ex. i have list of 15 questions and i want to show 2 questions with 2 same fragments in same activity then on click next i want to save that state and again want to load 3rd question only with same frag on same activity and on click previous i want that 2 fragments with 1 and 2 questions i am so confused and not understanding how to do if anyone can help.

this is my json for some survey.

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "q_id": "1",
      "que": "how many working vehicles do you have?",
      "q_type": "type_number",
      "ans_id": "",
      "ans": "",
      "Option": [
        {
          "op_id": "1",
          "op_val": "1"
        },
        {
          "op_id": "2",
          "op_val": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "q_id": "2",
      "que": "how many peoples are there in your house?",
      "q_type": "type_number",
      "ans_id": "",
      "ans": "",
      "Option": [
        {
          "op_id": "1",
          "op_val": "1"
        },
        {
          "op_id": "2",
          "op_val": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my code which im doing.
i just added all questions in one layout i really dont know how to do what i asked for in question and how to also preserve states for next and previous buttons, i have heard about singleton and something else but i dont know how to implement what i want.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);


    baseFragment = new BaseFragment();

    questions = Questions.AddAllQue(this);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());

    for(int i=0;i<questions.size();i++ ){

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("question",questions.get(i));

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(linearLayout,basefragment)
                .commit();
    }
    flContainer.addView(linearLayout);
```

}

i want something like this red marked are saperate but same base fragment.

and on click next same base fragment with only one question and on click previous again like this image i mean same state.

[image]

Comment: If the view would have n amount of question items it would be better to use custom view instead of fragments. Then you would only need to do `linearLayout.addView(new QuestionView(...));` and no need for that transaction crap. Or use ListView or RecyclerView.

Comment: I don't think you can just add fragments like that to a dynamically generated view in a reliable way, You'd need something similar to what FragmentPagerAdapter is doing.

Comment: @vilpe89 then how can i preserve the view state for next and previous button and when click on previous that view should place at there !!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sorry but i dont think !! there will be some ways the problem is that i dont know about as i am a beginner and i have searched a lot also. the requirement is like this only so i guess if someone have any kind of work before so!

Answer (score 0):

While I think you will have several more detailed questions as you make progress, it sounds like you need some overall direction to really get started.

To start I would suggest you don't want to use the *same* fragment for each of your two displayed questions, but rather two separate instances of the the same fragment class.  For example I think you would want to have something like this:

```
questionOneFragment = new BaseFragment();
questionTwoFragment = new BaseFragment();
```

It looks like you have a list of questions and you just want to display two at a time so I think the only state you need to maintain is what which question number data should be displayed in `questionOneFragment` (`questionTwoFragment` should display the data for the question in the list after question two).

All you would need for that would be a single integer `firstDisplayedQuestion` that you increment and decrement based on clicks on the `prev` and `next` button.  You need to managed the bounds of that variable so that it does not go below 0 or above 1 below the last item in your list.

In your `BaseFragment` class you need to have methods that set the UI elements you wish to display.  Then when a `prev` or `next` button is clicked, you update the `firstDisplayedQuestion` accordingly.  You also then get the data for the question in the list corresponding to `firstDisplayedQuestion` and call the display setting methods on `questionOneFragment` using that data. Next you get the data for the question in the list corresponding to `firstDisplayedQuestion + 1` and use that data to set the display elements of `questionTwoFragment`

Comment: as you said im thinking the same as two instance but the problem is that i want to display two instance at same time in one activity and then when i click next it should replace that with other single instance at same place and single question and when click previous it should add back that 2 instance at same place. im sorry if it sounds something weird but the requirement is like this only.

Comment: i am partially understanding but it is bit difficult for me to get overall idea about it as i dont have much experience and placing 2 fragments in the container again on click previous is difficult as of now so i will appricate if you can suggest some code or some detailed idea.

Comment: I am not sure why you feel you need to swap out various fragments.  You should be thinking of a fragment as a display element, ie a "view".  Rather than maintaining a list of fragments that you swap into your activity, you should just a the 2 instances added to your view and then change what they display rather than changing the fragment.